# Why am I getting an NaN value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My jQuery is:

```
$("#listDB").on("change", ".qfStyle", function(event) {
    var id = $(this).parents("tr").find('.itemCbox').val();
    $qnty = $("#qnty"+id);
    $unit = $("#unit"+id);
    $price = $("#price"+id);

    if($(this).parents("tr").find('.pbo').text()=="Kilos")
    {
        if(this.value<1)
        {
            $qnty.text(this.value*1000);
            $unit.text("gm");

            var data = "action=getPrice&id="+id;
            $.post("addBill.php", data, function(json) {
                alert(json.price);
                $price.text(json.price*this.value);
            }, 'json');
        }
    }
});
```

The JSON data returned by the server is:

> {"price":"52.00"}

Here, `this` refers to a textbox. I'm getting the value `NaN` for the expression:

```
$price.text(json.price*this.value);
```

But I've ensured that both `this.value` and `json.price` are both numbers. So, why do I get NaN when I multiply them?

Comment: (1) i think use  : json.price.value (2) try to $.get method

Comment: Because `this.value` is no longer accessible due to scope. Store the value of this into another variable and use that variable to get the price.

Comment: Please assign this.value to a variable. for example $price = $("#price"+id); $value = this.value; then change the line $price.text(json.price*this.value); to $price.text(json.price* $value); if it's not working please convert this variables to decimal before multiply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `this` isn't in a scope of a `post` function.

Check the code below. I added a new variable `value` which holds the value of `this.value` and which should be available even in a `post` function.

```
$("#listDB").on("change", ".qfStyle", function(event) {
    var id = $(this).parents("tr").find('.itemCbox').val();
    $qnty = $("#qnty"+id);
    $unit = $("#unit"+id);
    $price = $("#price"+id);

    var value = this.value;

    if($(this).parents("tr").find('.pbo').text()=="Kilos")
    {
        if(value<1)
        {
            $qnty.text(value*1000);
            $unit.text("gm");

            var data = "action=getPrice&id="+id;
            $.post("addBill.php", data, function(json) {
                alert(json.price);
                $price.text(json.price*value);
            }, 'json');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Number() to extract a string number to number format.

```js
function getStringNumber(stringNumber){
  var formatNumber = Number(stringNumber);
  console.log(formatNumber);
}
```

```html
<html>
<button onclick="getStringNumber('24.00')"> Convert String Number </button>  
</html>
```